# Connect / node.js - creating a simple server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, coffeescript, node.js-connect

I'm trying to get connect / node.js to work together nicely and simply.
I have the following (in Coffeescript):

```
connect = require('connect')
io = require('socket.io')

server = connect.createServer(
    connect.favicon()
  , connect.logger()
  , connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
).listen(8000)

socket = io.listen(server)
socket.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  socket.send({ hello: 'world' })
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'listeners' of undefined
```

It seems the server is not being initialized in time for the socket to start listening.

Compare with:

```
io = require ("socket.io")
http = require('http')

server = http.createServer()

server.listen(8000)

socket = io.listen(server)

socket.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  socket.send({ hello: 'world' })
```

Which does work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because `.listen()` returns something else. It should work if you  rewrite your code like this:

```
connect = require('connect')
io = require('socket.io')

server = connect.createServer(
    connect.favicon()
  , connect.logger()
  , connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
)
server.listen(8000)

socket = io.listen(server)
socket.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  socket.send({ hello: 'world' })
```

Comment: Thank you! Working. 
So, I was setting server to the result of the listen method, rather than defining it, and calling listen on it.. Ah.