# Do angular views work when a site is served from the local file system?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using angular to develop an application.  I'm developing off my local file system, on Windows.  However, when I enable `angular-route.js`, whenever I hit `index.html` with my browser, it instead goes to `index.html#/C:/`.

My route definition is:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
}
```

I think this causes the site to break, because `/C:/` doesn't match any angular routes.  What's going wrong?  How do I fix this?

Comment: yes angular js will work from local.

Comment: please post your route definition

Answer (score 7):

For routing & ajax (& more) to work properly, run a local development server; avoid use of `file://` for development, since browsers have different rules for it.

Tools like `yeoman` + `generator-angular` will automatically set up a gruntfile with a `server` task, which will run a `node-connect` server to locally serve your files.

You can do this with

- python:  (3)`python -m http.server 8001` (replace http.server with SimpleHttpServer in 2)
- [node.js + connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960090/connect-node-js-creating-a-simple-server)
- [ruby + rack](http://blog.samsonis.me/2010/02/rubys-python-simplehttpserver/)
- From the angularjs tutorial ([number 5 under "working with the code"](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)) - "You need an http server running on your system, but if you don't already have one already installed, you can use node to run scripts\web-server.js, a simple bundled http server."

---

Response from comments: For phonegap, use [the phonegap tools](https://npmjs.org/package/phonegap). It does exactly what I said, it runs a [local server.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/search?q=server)

Comment: I believe the phonegap tools are designed to compile and package phonegap applications locally or remotely, and to run the resulting builds in simulators.  Not to serve files locally.

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/blob/e6b76e1627713c02c5fa02ead0cc06c63f9b7749/lib/phonegap/app.js#L27 - "Creates a local server to serve up the project. The intended receiver is the PhoneGap App but any browser can consume the content."

Comment: Also, edited: the angular tutorial itself tells you to run an http server. There's probably something that says that you can't run it off of `file://`, but it's not worth finding, because I know it's true; you can't run it off of `file://`; angular can't parse the windows path as a root directory because it's not a url it would ever encounter in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
angular.module('MainModule', []).config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $routeProvider.when('/', {template: './js/templates/home.html', controller:HelloWorldCtrl});
    $routeProvider.when('/other', {template: './js/templates/other.html'});
});
```

In index HTML you need to specify templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" src="./js/templates/home.html"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="./js/templates/other.html"></script>
```